Flir one edge pro Wireless Model connecton with mobile sdk
I’m trying to connect the FLIR One Edge Pro wireless model to my custom Android application using the latest version of the Mobile SDK. I'm using the CommunicationInterface.Network connection interface, but the app is unable to establish a connection. It keeps searching for the camera without finding it. However, the connection works fine when using the official FLIR One application.
